# Unable to create branches on Subversion repository using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have pulled down a completely fresh checkout of our Subversion repository. Next I right click on the working folder and select "Branch/Tag". I give the branch a name, and select to have the copy made from my working copy. I also select to switch the working copy to the new branch.

When I click OK, I receive the following error:

```
Commit failed (details follow): 
Directory 'C:\Projects\StrattonWF_2' is out of date
File not found: transaction '8877-59x', path 
'/branches/foo/bar/'
You have to update your working copy first.
```

However, following the instructions in the error message and updating the working copy does not help - the error keeps happening.

This is only happening on my workstation - noone else has this issue. I can also do commits to the trunk fine. Like I said, I have pulled down a completely fresh copy of the trunk.

What else can I try?

The relevant version numbers are:

- TortoiseSVN 1.8.4
- Subversion 1.8.5
- Client operating system: Windows XP

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I figured this out: I was trying to create a branch with two folders in the path, i.e. /branches/foo/bar/. The operation failed because the first subfolder didn't exist.

There is actually an option at the bottom of the branch options window in TortoiseSVN's called "Create intermediate folders" which defaults to off. I guess that makes sense now.

It would be nice if TortoiseSVN provided a more helpful error message.

Comment: This isn't really TortoiseSVN's fault.  It's Subversion's fault.  We should be providing a better error.  I suspect the problem here is that we're returning a 409 http status code someplace where we shouldn't.  I know we made some changes to address some of this, but I'm not sure about this specific case.  It'd probably be helpful to drop an email to users@subversion.apache.org describing what you were doing and the error message you got.  That way we'll be sure to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll send them an email.

Comment: Just checking the "Create intermediate folders" solved my issue.

Comment: On the command line use the --parents option to create missing intermediate directories.

Comment: You should accept this as answer for your question. It really solves the problem.

Comment: ... saved my ar***!

Answer (score 0):

This is some sort of issue on the server side.  There's a couple possible issues that come to mind.

- You're running through a proxy server that is timing out the request and then repeating the request, which is then generating an error due to two commands failing.
- Someone modified the Subversion repository without restarting the server.  E.G. someone ran a dump/load cycle and then replaced the repository (fixing this could be a simple as restarting the daemon).
- The repository has some corruption in it.

What's in the error_log and access_log for the repository when you try to do this?  If I could see those I probably could tell you which of these are likely.